# Using SLD Filter Difference

Tags: postgis, sld, filter

I have a PostGIS table with polygon geometries.

I would like to create an sld which first does an inside buffer, and then a difference between the buffer and the original geometry.

This is basically like cutting a hole out of the polygon....ie first buffer (say...50 meters) and then cut this buffered polygon out of the original polygon.

I can´t seem to get my head around the syntax of using the sld filter explained here

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html

```xml
<Intersects>
<PropertyName>GEOMETRY</PropertyName>
<Literal>
<gml:Point>
<gml:coordinates>1 1</gml:coordinates>
</gml:Point>
</Literal>
</Intersects>
```

This is an intersect function which only displays the points which intersect 1,1. I guess a DIFFERENCE function with a buffer would have to be somehow nested...but I don´t know if this is possible.

---

A donut is exactly what I am after. I have to create a symbol for a polygon geometry. This sumbol is made up of a thin outline and a thick band which is inside the polygon (150m width).
I have tried to create this using sld but without success. I really don´t want to have to create new geometries in order to symbolize one polygon theme which is why i´m asking if this is possible using just an sld file and one postgis table.

You can take a look at the screenshot here:

http://maps.zgb.de/rrop/sld_img/screenshot-band.png

This was achieved using a buffered polygon and not using an SLD filter function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<PolygonSymbolizer>
          <Geometry>
        <ogc:Function name="difference">    
          <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Function name="buffer">
            <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>-50</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:Function>
          </ogc:Function>
          </Geometry>
          <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#894465</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</CssParameter>  
        </Fill>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
```

It works in geoserver 2.7-SNAPSHOT (rev 38562)